# Let Z ∼ N(0,1). Find the probability density function of |Z|

Tags: probability-theory

So I can easily find the pdf for the standard normal(though its too complicated to write out here), but how would the absolute value sign change the outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $W=|Z|$. We find the cumulative distribution function $F_W(w)$ of $W$, and then differentiate to find the density function $f_W(w)$.

First note that if $w\lt 0$ then $F_W(w)=0$. So if $w\lt 0$ then $f_W(w)=0$.

Now let $w\gt 0$. We have
$$F_W(w)=\Pr(|Z|\le w)=2\Pr(0\le Z\le w)=2\int_0^w f_Z(z)\,dz,$$
where $f_Z(z)$ is the density function of $Z$, which I also find too complicated to type.

Differentiate $F_W(w)$, using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. We get that for $w\gt 0$, $f_W(w)=2f_Z(w)$.